# i want to fetch specific years into a variable and later display it inside paragraph ,it is a javascript code to display 1st january is being sunday

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, casting

```js
 sunday();
 
 function sunday()
            {
              let result;
              let text1;
              let year;
            for (year = 2014; year <= 2050; year++)
        {
        
        var d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
        if (d.getDay() === 0 )
       
             console.log("1st January is being a Sunday  "+year);

             text1+=year.toString();//not get stored in variable text1

        result=text1.toString();//same problem here also
    
    
    
    
        }
    
    }
```

**please tell me why i cant store those years into text1(variable) even after i convert into string format also when i check console everything is works perectly in console result but it wont work when i store and try to display through paragraph using .innerhtml  property help me to display it inside paragraph inner text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error near your if statement, you forgot to insert brackets.
Also, you can't append a text to a variable only defined with let.
If it's a string, you should do `let text1 = ""`
Furthermore, it is not very useful to append multiple results to the same string, which only gives something like this : "20172030" etc... by appending years. I think what you are trying to do is use arrays, which can be initialized by doing : `let text1 = []`

The code works and should look like this :

```js
function sunday(){
    let result;
    let text1 = [];
    let year;

    for (year = 2014; year <= 2050; year++){
        var d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
        if (d.getDay() == 0 ){
            console.log("1st January is being a Sunday  "+year);
            text1.push(year.toString());
            console.log(text1);
            result = text1.join(",");
            console.log(result)
        }
    }
}

sunday()
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several problems here

Firstly you are not initializing the variable `text1` with a string value. So the value of this will become a string `undefined` in a string concatenating context (your `+=` in `text1+=year.toString()`)

See these examples for a demonstration

```js
let x
x+="2021"
console.log(x) // Output undefined2021
```

```js
let x = "" // x is initialized with an empty string
x+="2021"
console.log(x) // Output 2021
```

Then we do not know, in which context you are calling the function. At least you do not return any value from it. If you add `return text1` at the end of the function, your code might work.